# Where does inconsistent margins in headings come from?

Tags: css, margin

In this example http://dabblet.com/gist/708f69e9c5352f67f514 the heading "Article 1" is inconsistently pushed down, while it should appear on the same height as "Intro" and "Article 2". Where does this margin come from? When i change the h1-style to `h1 {margin-top: 0}` all headings appear horizontally aligned, but when i use higher values like `h1 {margin-top: 60px}` , then the inconsistency always appears. What's going on here? How can i use a margin without having this annoying inconsistency?

The Code:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 460px;
    top: 0;

      -moz-column-count: 2;
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      column-count: 2;

      column-gap: 40px;
      -moz-column-gap: 40px;
      -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 36px;
}


<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <article>
                <h1>Intro</h1>
                <p>Llorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

            <div class="right">
                <article>
                    <h1>Article 1</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h1>Article 1</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</p>
                </article>
            </div> <!-- ds-right -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Something like the following [Link](http://dabblet.com/gist/466ed90e18afea9d0956)?

Comment: No, when adding a value of 77px (for example) for margin-top of h1, then the inconsistencies reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to reset any margin on the `h1` and `p` tags like so `p,h1{margin:0}` then set the container for the floated columns to overflow:hidden which will container the floats

Comment: I don't understand your answer: could you set up a copy of my example dabblet?

Comment: Okay, i got it. Your solution works. Here is some background information: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/